# Single Bluetooth headset detected as multiple devices; not all of them function

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, bluetooth, headset

A single Treks Air Bluetooth headset paired to Windows 10 appears as several devices. I wouldn't mind this if they all worked, but many times only one of them works. And it's hard to tell which one will work. (I think it keeps changing.)

What is the difference between:

- Headset
- Headphones
- Communications - Headset

How can I reduce this to a single device, or make sure they all work, or at least predict which device will work?

When I pair this headset to other devices like an iPhone, only one Bluetooth device appears.

---

**Screenshots for context:**

**There is only one "Trekz" device in Bluetooth settings:**

[image]

**There are two different "Trekz" devices when I click the speaker in the system tray:**

[image]

**It's even worse in an app like Google Voice. Up to five different "Trekz" devices appear!**

[image]